# SonarQube not displaying Issue Filter on Dashboard for all users

Tags: sonarqube

I'm configuring the home Dashboard in SonarQube that everyone will see, even of they have not logged in. I've added the Projects, Most Violated Rules, Quality Gate and Metric Hotspot widgets to the Dashboard so far and that all works great even for anonymous users.

The problem I'm having is adding a Issue Filter widget. I created the Issue Filter and shared it will all users, added a widget to the Dashboard using that filter. But that component only displays when I log in. I'm assuming the issue is that anonymous users cannot see the Issue filter I've created, is there anyway around that?

Comment: What version of SonarQube do you have ? 
What is in the issue filter ? Anything specific ?

Comment: I'm running 5.1.2, the Issue Filter is a simple one displaying all the New Issues from the Last week, an anonymous user can go in an create a filter just like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Administrator to modify default dashboard and add this widget. It will be available to everyone. However the filter used might need to be shared with everyone to make it work.